# Onblur call to js is not responding when using match function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="frmfeed" method="post" action="demo/admin/formprocess.php" onSubmit="return validate_form()">
<table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Name Of Applicant</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" class="input_style"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mobile Number: (10 Digit)*</td>
        <td><input id="number" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="input_style" onblur=" if(checkPhone(this.value)==false){this.value=''}"/></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

This is javascript code that I have used:

```
function checkPhone(input) {
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    if(input.value.match(phoneno);
    {return false;}
    return true;
}
```

I am trying to validate the phone number entered by the user but  match function is not working. I cant find the error. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Maybe the `;` on the end of your if statement condition is causing an issue, also you never close your condition. *missing `)` at the end*

Comment: @learner Your already passing the value to checkPhone function rather than the input object so use input.match(phoneno);

Comment: i added semi colon. It is still not working. and input.match() wasn't working which is why i added .value

Comment: LOOK at your developer console. Learn to use it and it will point you to errors in your code.  Also clearing out an input on focus or because it has an error is really bad user experience..

Comment: what is the correct way to deal with invalid input

Answer (score 0):

Check with following function

```
    function checkPhone(input) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{10,10}$/);

        if(pattern.test(input)) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
```

If returns true then match is correct else test pattern is wrong.

Comment: this doesn't work. I have tried this many times. I made a few syntactical errors while posting it but i was working with the same code you have written here.

Comment: not working. is there something that i need to include in my php files to use these functions. I am new to all this and very confused. Thanks for your help

Comment: I had made some mistakes. It worked now. thanks a lot for your help.